# What is the Big-O complexity of a general tree?

Tags: data-structures

What I mean by general tree is an unbalanced tree with multiple child nodes (not restricted to 2 child node for each branch like Binary Tree). What is the Big-O complexity of remove node, insert node, find node

Answer (score 1):

The average time complexity of searching in balanced BST in O(log(n)). The worst case complexity of searching in unbalanced binary tree is O(n).

Comment: More generally, the average time complexity of all three operations that the OP asks about in a d-ary tree is `O(log-base-d(n))`. Granted, we ignore constants (like the base of the logarithm) in asymptotic analysis, so `O(log(n))` is in fact correct.

Comment: OP isn't asking exclusively about binary trees, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a regular k-ary tree that does nothing special with its data, then to find any one node in the tree would take `O(n)` time assuming there are `n` nodes.

Inserting a node would be `O(1)` since you can store it wherever you want, and removing a node would be `O(n)` since you'd have to look at every node (worst case) to find the one to delete, and since there's no order to the data you don't have to do anything with the rest of the nodes.

Comment: Inserting a node would still be O(n) worst case unless you're inserting at root.